# Get only leaf nodes from Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I would like to filter out only leaf nodes (folders) from `Get-ChildItem`, those ones that do not contain any other folders in them.

Here is my current query:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory -Exclude "*SubStr*"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He was on the right path, but just forgot the -Directory on the second Get-ChildItem command.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory -Exclude "*SubStr*" | Where-Object { -not (Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Directory) }
```

Note: If you want to find hidden folders you will have to use -Force on both Get-ChildItem commands in the line below.

Answer (score 0):

You would need another filter to establish whether or not the folder has anything inside it:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory -Exclude "*SubStr*" | Where-Object { -not (Get-ChildItem $_.FullName) }
```

Comment: Not 100% correct, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

`Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory -Exclude "*SubStr*" |?{$_.psiscontainer}`

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.